# Optical Flow Using Lucas-Kanade

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking

Currently, I'm using Vibe to store contour data, and after calculating the centroid of each contour, the Lucas-Kanade tracker is initiated. The initiation is working fine, but the problem is with the tracking after wards. If I'm manually initializing the points, then the tracker is working fine. But if I'm initializing it through a vector of centroids of contours(fbseparat), it is not tracking. I have attached the Lucas-Kanade code.

```
for (int m = 1; m <= frameNumber; m++)
{
    //featuresCurrent.clear();
    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty())
        break;

    if (!(fbseparat[m][0].x == 0) && !(fbseparat[m][0].y == 0)) {
        addRemovePt = true;
    }


    frame.copyTo(image);
    cvtColor(image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);



    //if( needToInit )
    //{
    // automatic initialization
    goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, featuresCurrent, MAX_COUNT, ..)
        cornerSubPix(gray, featuresCurrent, subPixWinSize, termcrit)

        addRemovePt = false;
    //}  
    if (!featuresPrevious.empty())
    {
        buildOpticalFlowPyramid(gray, pyramid, winSize, 500, bool...)
            vector<uchar> status;
        vector<float> err;
        if (prevGray.empty())
            gray.copyTo(prevGray);
        calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevGray, gray, featuresPrevious,

            featuresCurrent, status, err, winSize, 3, termcrit, 0, 0.001);
        size_t i, k;

        cout << "Point 1 initial size:" << featuresCurrent.size() << "\n";
        for (i = k = 0; i < featuresCurrent.size(); i++)
        {
            if (addRemovePt)
            {
                if (norm(fbseparat[m][i] - featuresCurrent[i]) <= 5)
                {
                    addRemovePt = false;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (!status[i])
                continue;

            featuresCurrent[k++] = featuresCurrent[i];

            circle(image, featuresCurrent[i], 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8);
        }

        featuresCurrent.resize(k);

    }


    cout << "Frame Number:" << m;
    cout << "Point 1 size: " << featuresCurrent.size() << "\n";
    cout << "Point 0 size: " << featuresPrevious.size() << "\n";

    if (addRemovePt && featuresCurrent.size() < (size_t)MAX_COUNT)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= countoursinframe[m]; j++)
        {
            vector<Point2f> tmp;

            tmp.push_back(fbseparat[m][j]);
            cornerSubPix(gray, tmp, winSize, Size(-1, -1), termcrit);
            featuresCurrent.push_back(tmp[0]);
            addRemovePt = false;

        }

    }

    //needToInit = false;
    imshow("LK Win", image);

    char c = (char)waitKey(10);
    if (c == 27)
        break;
    switch (c)
    {
        // case 'r':
        //     //needToInit = true;
        //     break;
    case 'c':
        featuresPrevious.clear();
        featuresCurrent.clear();
        break;
    }
}
```